# Stripe Elements: Styling issues

Tags: javascript, css, stripe-payments

Previously we had custom forms and everything was working as expected, but as we switched to Stripe Elements (Due to PCI restrictions) problems started appearing in our road. This UI is so complicated, I don't even understand what's wrong here? We're using our font, font-size and weight to match other fields, but it's just not the same as other inputs.

Field at the top is our custom one and in the below there's a Stripe Element.

Why does the font-weight size and even the font-family seems not the same as in the top, what I'm missing?

The thing is that in the html if you inspect the input itself it shows that the styles are correctly assigned, but they don't seem to be the same as they should.

And even the padding seems not to work as expected, in other inputs we're using the same padding and it fills the entire height

[image]

```
            var elements = window.stripe.elements();
            var card = elements.create('cardNumber', {
                style: {
                    base: {
                        color: '#000929', // color of the text : https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style 
                        fontWeight: 500,
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        fontFamily: 'Plus Jakarta Sans, sans-serif',
                        '::placeholder': {
                            color: '#adb3bd',
                            fontWeight: 500,
                        },
                    },
                }
            });

            card.mount('#id_card_number');
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you have something in your HTML/styles preventing the style to be applied. It's best to provide a live URL to inspect. AFAICS styling on Stripe Examples works: https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples/blob/master/js/example1.js#L20-L25 and https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/